Multivariate Linear Mixed Model
I want to make a multivariate linear mixed model with the variables slope_reactivity, peak_reactivity, and slope_recovery as dependent variables and normalized_CTseverity, gender, age_years and binary_diagnosis and dependent variables. study is the random effect.
I got as far as this code:
model_cortisol <- lmer(slope_reactivity + slope_recovery + 
   peak_reactivity ~ normalized_CTseverity + age_years + 
   gender + binary_diagnosis + (1 | study), 
   data = df_sum_cort)

However this only gives me the effect of normalized_CTseverity etc on slope_reactivity, slope_recovery and peak_reactivity together as a whole. I also want the effect of the independent variables on the dependent variables separate from each other.
How do I do this? Do I change something in the code of my model or can I do some sort of post hoc test? I don't want to do separate models as the slope_reactivity, slope_recovery and peak_reactivity are strongly linked.

You aren't fitting the model you think you are. Whatever is on the left-hand side of the formula is evaluated as a standard expression, so your response variable is actually the sum of all four values (probably not what you want).
In order to fit a multivariate response in lme4, you have to convert your data to long format, with one row for each measurement (and a variable indexing the original observation).  tidyr::pivot_longer is the easiest way to do this, e.g.
df_sum_cort$obs <- factor(seq(nrow(df_sum_cort)))
long_df <- dplyr::pivot_longer(df_sum_cort,
   c(slope_reactivity, slope_recovery, peak_reactivity),
   names_to = "var")

which will create variables var, value. Then:
model_cortisol <- lmer(value ~ 0 + var +
  var:(normalized_CTseverity + age_years + 
        gender + binary_diagnosis) +
   (0 + var | obs) + (1|study),
   data = df_long,
   control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nlev = "ignore",
                         check.nobs.vs.rankZ = "ignore"))

This will estimate separate effects for each response variable (the overall intercept is suppressed with 0+) and correlations between the responses.  The random effects components will be a bit wonky because they're confounded with the residual variance, but the fixed effects should be interpretable.
See also https://rpubs.com/bbolker/3336

I thought that 0+var on the left hand side of the pipe in your random effect term has the effect of constraining correlations to be zero. But you state that this formula will estimate "correlations between the responses". Can you please clarify?
